# Is there anything wrong with structuring php code like this?

Tags: php

I hope this questions isn't to ridiculous.

Is there anything wrong with structuring php code like the example below, because with some multi-line scripts it looks so ugly and my ocd doesn't allow myself to look past it. Or is there a prettier way of writing? Thanks everyone

example

```
$example         = 1;
$exmaple_this    = 1;
$example_for_you = 1;
```

rather than

```
$example=1;
$exmaple_this=1;
$example_for_you=1;
```

Comment: Code formatting is a notoriously subjective thing. If you're working in a team, you'll need to follow the established standards, or agree some between you to avoid arguments. If you're working on your own, you do you. :)

Comment: It's just a matter of preference. Format it the way that makes sense for you. My personal preference is like the first example since I think it's easer to read, but again, that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: I prefer the first, because I'm anal.

Comment: In my highly subjective opinion, second style wouldn't be so bad if it didn't pack everything together, without spaces between tokens. I guess I'm old. First style makes much sense when variables are related, otherwise it just causes unnecesary changes in diffs are you add or remove variables.